# How to execute php script in background process?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, phpmailer

I am developing a mail sending module in php; where I will be fetching 
email id from database and will send a message to that email id. I will also be updating database with the information I sent in mail and also will display delivered information.

**My Problem:**

It takes more time to send mail; so until mail is not sent the database does not get updated and the delivered information is also not displayed; So, I planned to run mailing functionality in background process and I came across this piece of code which was similar; but I am unable to understand it. Would any one help me?

```
shell_exec("/path/to/php /path/to/send_notifications.php '".$post_id."' 'alert' >> /path/to/alert_log/paging.log &")
```

Comment: How about reading the documentation of `shell_exec()` ?

Comment: ya i am reading, but is there any other solution to over come this problem?

Comment: If this works, why do you need another solution? just curious. By the way, if your task is required to run periodically, cron job helps too

Comment: oh that file i will try it out thank you.

Comment: scary looking code! `$post_id`

Comment: why not create a cron job?

Comment: @self, that is nor my code , i found it while searching about my problem.

Comment: yep i am trying it out...